# icacls on windows 7 not working, Permission denied when saving an image file

Tags: security, windows, permissions

I have been trying to solve this for 2 hours, on linux this is very easy. Please kindly help me.

I keep getting this error :

```
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi\images): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

So i asked google, and i tried some solution but none of them work. This is what i did :

```
icacls C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi /grant Everyone:F /t
```

This is the SS of the file's properties :

[image]

This is the "sharing" tab, also full control to everyone :

[image]

The permission to everyone and current user has been on "full control", but i still got that error. I need to do something like **chmod 777** on windows.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

exec('whoami') returning "tama-pc\tama" and get_current_user() returning "Tama".

So, based on the data aboved i followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538806/enable-php-access-to-folder-in-windows by create a new user with **full permission** : "Tama-PC/Tama".

Then, i changed the XAMPP owner and the HTTPD owner to "Tama-PC/Tama". I also change the `user` and `group` on the HTTPD config file to :

```
user Tama
group Tama-PC
```

The default for both of them is `daemon`.

Unfortunately, none of them work.

Comment: Don't share the folder, unless you need it accessible from other machines. Which user account is PHP running as?  ["Everyone" is _not_ everyone](http://weaselfire.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/everyone-isnt-everyone/)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Do u mean which account i logged in to windows when coding?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 i only have 1 account in my windows, so i logged in to that account.

Comment: Still struggling for this one. Any help please?

Comment: I'll ask again, Which user account is PHP/Webserver service running as?   Assuming you're the one who setup your web server and PHP, then you are the one who knows the answer to that. Figure that out and ensure that specific user has appropriate permissions to the folder.

Comment: exec('whoami') returns "tama-pc\\tama". On the folder's properties, "Tama-Pc/Users" has the full access. Thanks

Comment: safe mode is off, and file upload is on in the php.ini. I use XAMPP  on my windows.